# What can be the maximum "POST" size I can have?

Tags: google-app-engine, http, python-2.7, post, http-post

Sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I couldn't find any substantial info on my concern.

Currently, I have a Java-GWT application which invokes a python script deployed on app engine. They communicate via REST.

So what is the maximum size for POST method I can send to Google App Engine where the script is deployed?

Is the limit same as specified in the link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-java/5V9W9ibq4Ns. Also any difference if we use Python instead of Java.

Answer (score 6):

On GAE the [incoming request can not be longer](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Requests) than 32Mb. This includes the whole request size (command, path, headers), not only POST body. This is language independent.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Google doc

> Static data limit
> In all languages except Go, no single static data file can be larger than 32MB. The limit for Go is 64MB.